# I can't take screenshots in android emulator AVD manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

This error appears when I click on screenshot icon, what is the reason?

[image: android emulator]

Answer (score 0):

If your emulator is running Android 4.4 or I think 4.3, then screen capture functionality is broken -- you'll have to use a physical device to get screenshots on those OS versions.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359

Comment: hi, this error happens also with API 21 and 23 @User54321